# problem when deploy app to website ionic --v 6.12.2

Tags: ionic-framework, indexing, webdeploy, ionic5, vs-web-site-project

[image]

in ionic 4 The content was showing the www Less and works when pressing on index,
But here the content appears www the more file
It does not work when pressing on the the index

Comment: how are you deploying it?

Comment: i use ionic build -- release --prod
and upload file (content www) to website